# Blur HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How can I blur the contents of an HTML5 canvas?

I know that I can use CSS, but I need to blur the contents of the canvas so that I can manipulate it later.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you! I think that I have found just what I needed. Can I mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: Your question was closed as a duplicate, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native function to do that. But you can implement your own image filter operations by using `context.getImageData` to get an array of raw RGBA values of the canvas data, do your filter operation on that data, and then write it back with `context.putImageData`.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation